# How do I execute pyinstaller?

Tags: python, installation, pyinstaller

Although I did the pyinstaller installation process correctly, but when I type pyinstaller in cmd, it gives me this error, how do I solve it?

```
C:\Users\Alireza>pyinstaller
'pyinstaller' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I wrote "pip install pyinstaller" in command prompt, but after that when I wrote "pyinstaller" gave the above error.
what can I do?

Comment: are you using the right virtual environment?

Comment: What was your installation process?

Comment: @sinapourkashani Hey, you only need one of those. Where did you get your installation instructions from? Are you running it from within a virtual environment? What version of Python are you using? This question is missing crucial information. Please edit the question to elaborate on both the environment you are operating within as well as the installation steps taken.